# Spark: JavaRDD.map does not accept anonymous function

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to convert `JavaRDD<String>` to `JavaRDD<Row>` using an anonymous function. Here is my code:

```
JavaRDD<String> listData = jsc.textFile("/src/main/resources/CorrectLabels.csv");
JavaRDD<Row> jrdd = listData.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
                    public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
                        String[] fields = record.split(",");
                        return RowFactory.create(fields[1], fields[0].trim());
                    }
                });
```

But on doing this, I get back an error as :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Details of Stack:

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.cpny.ml.supervised.FeatureExtractor, value: com.cpny.ml.supervised.FeatureExtractor@421056e5)
    - field (class: com.cpny.ml.supervised.FeatureExtractor$1, name: this$0, type: class com.cpny.ml.supervised.FeatureExtractor)
    - object (class com.cpny.ml.supervised.FeatureExtractor$1, com.cpny.ml.supervised.FeatureExtractor$1@227a47)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Thanks! K

Comment: What is `FeatureExtractor`?

Comment: FeatureExtractor is the class name - where the anony function is present..

Comment: Show us a complete code reproduce. If `FeatureExtractor` is being serialized, you're using it in a closure somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you are getting is not related to the anonymous function.

The `FeatureExtractor` class is either not `Serializable` or contains non-`Serializable` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @slovit..
My earlier setup was : MainClass calling FeatureExtractor to get the JavaRDD. This class was not `Serializable` before. Now after making it one, I no longer get the issue..

But on another note, MainClass was my starting point to submit a SparkJob as:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.cpny.ml.supervised.MainClass --master spark://localhost:7077 /mltraining/target/mltraining-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But the `MainClass` is not marked as `Serializable`. But when I include the anonymous function in `MainClass`, I dont get the issue. How the MainClass got Serialized but another class did not?

PS: May be this is not a spark question, but a basic java question.. sorry!

Comment: It's difficult to answer such a question if you don't see code. Most likely you were passing an instance of `FeatureExtractor` to a Spark transformation. But again, it's difficult to answer for sure without the actual code.